# Одновременный запуск 14 скриптов python

Tags: python, многопоточность, multiprocessing

уважаемые.
Есть такой вопрос. Как реализовать запуск 14 Python скриптов одновременно через один.
Все скрипты по сути дубликаты друг друга. Находятся в разных папках, так как для для каждого создается отдельное небольшое дб и каждый работает с отдельным для него txt-файлом со строками.
Просто хочется решить вопрос одним скриптом, не открывая кучу cmd, что бы в итоге не запутаться, нагрузка на машину по сути не имеет значение, скрипты простенькие в 50 строк. Нагрузка не большая.
Но, каждый надо держать отдельно, для мелких редакции.

За ранее буду очень благодарен за Вашу помощь.

Comment: Была такая идея, пробовал реализовать, но скрипт начинал крашится постоянно, хоть и простой. Но, спасибо что ответили

Answer (score 0, accepted):

скрипт на bash

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
/path_to_script/1.py &
/path_to_script/2.py &
```